# http page isn't downloaded fully QT

Tags: file, qt, http

Hello I wrote program that should download web page and save it as a file. It does it but partially  only. Have anybody encounterd such a problem?

mainwindow.cpp source file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    setFile("myPage");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    netManager->deleteLater();
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setFile(QString fileURL)
{
    QString savePath;

    savePath = QString("D:/page.html");

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(fileURL));
    reply = netManager->get(request);

    file = new QFile;
    file->setFileName(savePath);
    file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(onProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    connect(netManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onReplyFinished()));
}

void MainWindow::onProgress(qint64 bRead, qint64 bTotal)
{
    qDebug(QString::number(bRead).toLatin1() + " - " + QString::number(bTotal).toLatin1());
}

void MainWindow::onFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    switch (reply->error())
    {
    case QNetworkReply::NoError:
    {
        qDebug("File downloaded");
        qDebug() << file->size();
    }break;
    default:
    {
        qDebug(reply->errorString().toLatin1());
    }
    }
    if(file->isOpen())
    {
        file->close();
        file->deleteLater();
    }
}

void MainWindow::onReadyRead()
{
    file->write(reply->readAll());
}

void MainWindow::onReplyFinished()
{
    if(file->isOpen())
    {
        file->close();
        file->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

mainwindow.h header source file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QFile>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QStringList>

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void setFile(QString fileURL);
private slots:
    void onFinished(QNetworkReply *);
    void onProgress(qint64 bRead, qint64 bTotal);
    void onReadyRead();
    void onReplyFinished();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager *netManager;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    QFile *file;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I tried to solve it myself but after many tries I failed. I'm beginner in QT, so propably I've made a mistake somewhere, and I don't even see it. Can anybody drive me to a proper way to fix the problem?

Comment: Are you using Qt 4.x or Qt 5.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this:

```
connect(netManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

before:

```
reply = netManager->get(request);
```

Works fine after this modification ;)

Comment: Glad to help you ;) Netmanager's and reply's **onFinished** slots are used simultanously so you can resign from one of them.